# React reference subcomponent not rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In have a main React component and a subcomponent called `AttributeInput`.
In order to avoid code duplication, I extracted some code from my main component and placed it in a method from `AttributeInput`

I am trying to reference that code like this:

```
{this.state.attributeInput ? <AttributeInput ref="attributeInput"/> : null}

<div>
  {this.refs["attributeInput"].displayInputField(
      "List Name",
      "List Name(<15 characters - A-Z, 0-9 and _ only)",
      this.setListName
  )}
  {this.refs["attributeInput"].displayInputField(
      "List Description",
      "List Description",
      this.setListDescription
  )}
</div>
```

However, if `this.state.attributeInput` is false, `AttributeInput` will not be rendered. Therefore, when I reference it here,

```
this.refs["attributeInput"].displayInputField(
    "List Name",
    "List Name(<15 characters - A-Z, 0-9 and _ only)",
    this.setListName
)
```

I get an error saying that `AttributeInput` is undefined.

Can I reference `AttributeInput` if it's not rendered?
Is there an alternative to my approach?

Comment: You cannot access `refs` to other components inside `render` itself. What's the purpose of `AttributeInput` anyway? Why are you calling methods on it? Are you abusing React components as method bags?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to [communicate between two React components](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html), but you want to share code and call methods that exist on the `AttributeInput` component?

The easiest way to share code between components, is to separate the shared code out into a mixin.

```
var SharedCode = function() {
  return {
    displayInputField: function(name, description, other) {
      // ...
    }
  };
};
```

Then simply include this mixin in the components that need a `displayInputField` method.

```
var AttributeInput = React.createClass({
  mixins: [SharedCode]
});
```

After you have defined and included the mixin, you will be able to reference the newly added properties on `this`.

```
return (
  <div>
    {this.displayInputField(/* ... */)}
  </div>    
);
```